# Expression() command just prints itself

Tags: r

apologies for the trivial nature of this question. I have searched for other instances of this and can't find any.

I am trying to combine the `expression()` function with `paste()`, for example to do: `expression(paste("TNF", alpha))`

But everytime I enter a command using `expression()` I just get my command returned to me, so the above command just prints:
expression(paste("TNF", alpha))

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Nothing.  It's working as expected. From `?expression` - *`expression` returns a vector of type "expression" containing its arguments (unevaluated).*  What exactly are you trying to do?  I assume you are using this in a plot, which would get evaluated there.

Comment: Thanks @RichardScriven, I'm trying to include the alpha character in one level of my grouping variable, so that it is automatically used in the group labels in my plot (using ggplot2). Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Ah ok I had misinterpreted the function of`expression()` and it seems it's interpreted the way I wanted it to be within the `scale_x_discreet()` call when building my plot in ggplot2.

In case it's useful to anyone else, my code became (where `a` is a ggplot object):

```
a + scale_x_discrete(labels=c("Vehicle", expression(paste("TNF", alpha))))
```

Which then produced a group label of "TNFα".